# Unable to uncheck the check Box

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I am using CheckboxListTile in for check box. It works good if selected : false. If selected is true then unable to un check it.

```
final checkBox = CheckboxListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      title: Text("Remember Me", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
      selected: checkBoxState,
      value: checkBoxState,
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      activeColor: Colors.grey,
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          checkBoxState = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
```

This is the code what I am using.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: i think checkbox code is not re-render on setState.

Comment: @naseema please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are using `checkBox`, but this code works perfectly fine.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool checkBoxState = true;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return CheckboxListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      title: Text("Remember Me", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
      selected: checkBoxState,
      value: checkBoxState,
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      activeColor: Colors.grey,
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          checkBoxState = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like below. You need to set bool true false reversing inside setState like `checkBoxState = !checkBoxState;`. And declare bool globally. `bool checkBoxState = false;`

```
bool checkBoxState = false;

final checkBox = CheckboxListTile(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    title: Text("Remember Me", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
    selected: checkBoxState,
    value: checkBoxState,
    checkColor: Colors.white,
    activeColor: Colors.grey,
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
       onChanged: (newValue) {
         setState(() {
           checkBoxState = !checkBoxState;
         });
       },
   )
```

Comment: No it's not working. I tried your code, but not working. Check box is not working when checkBoxState is true.

Comment: If it is true. Then check box looks like disable state.

Comment: Can you explain what you need

Comment: @NaseemaShaik if you mark it once(true) it wont be false again!